# LINQ: Get all selected values of a CheckBoxList using a Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms

Consider a scenario where you want to retrieve a `List` or `IEnumerable` of the values of all the selected checkboxes in an `<asp:CheckBoxList>`.

Here's the current implementation:

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = (from item in chkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
                               where item.Selected 
                               select int.Parse(item.Value));
```

**Question**: How would you improve this LINQ query using a lambda expression or lambda syntax?

Comment: Background on the Cast(): the `.Cast<ListItem>()` is required because the CheckBoxList's collection of Items is of type `ListItemCollection`, and it doesn't have the `Where` extension method. Here's the exception raised: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection'.
'Where' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'item'.

Comment: @pcampbell - The `Cast` method was created to allow you to work around just these issues.  Basically it allows you to use the new shiny LINQ operators even with older types that don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. :)

Comment: Note that `Cast` actually has corresponding syntactic sugar - you could just as well write `from ListItem item in chkBoxList.Items`.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You *are* using lambda expressions - they are just concealed by your use of C#'s query operators.

Consider that this:

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = (from item in chkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
                               where item.Selected 
                               select int.Parse(item.Value));
```

Gets compiled to this:

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = chkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                              .Where(i => i.Selected)
                              .Select(i => int.Parse(i.Value));
```

As you can see you are already using two lambda expressions (they are the parameters to the `Where` and `Select` methods) and you didn't even know it!  This query is fine and I wouldn't change it at all.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I learned something today from your answer, so thank you. I'll mark this as the 'answer' although now I am questioning myself which is more readable to the developer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 23):

I would improve the query expression by making the call to `Cast<T>` implicit:

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = from ListItem item in chkBoxList.Items 
                              where item.Selected 
                              select int.Parse(item.Value);
```

When you specify the type of a range variable, the compiler inserts a call to `Cast<T>` for you.

Other than that, I entirely agree with Andrew.

EDIT: For GONeale:

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = chkBoxList.Items
                                        .Cast<ListItem>()
                                        .Where(item => item.Selected)
                                        .Select(item => int.Parse(item.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I have used this implicit cast as an enhancement to my query.

Comment: Jon, what would be the lambda [extension method based]-equivalent?

Comment: Thanks Jon.  How do you keep up with all the comments?? Do you get sent an email? ;)

Comment: Jon, ok, so `.Cast<ListItem>()` is the simplest in fluent syntax.  Got ya.  Thought you were indicating another way to do it implicitly or something. Graham