# how to get selected item in CheckBoxList in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a CheckBoxList in my page.is there any way to get all selected item values using linq?

what is the best way to get selected item values in CheckBoxList?

Comment: take a look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196007/linq-get-all-selected-values-of-a-checkboxlist-using-a-lambda-expression

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could go about this by taking the items of the checkbox list and converting them to ListItems and from that collection fetch those who is selected, like this:

```
var selectedItems = yourCheckboxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easy way

```
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem oItem in rdioListRoles.Items)
{
    if (oItem.Selected) // if you want only selected
    {
       variable  = oItem.Value;
    }
    // otherwise get for all items
    variable  = oItem.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<string> selectedValues = chkBoxList1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(li => li.Selected).Select(li => li.Value).ToList();
```