# How to use the same name in input checkbox when we use asp:CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I usually avoid asp: controls and always use pure html controls with `runat="server"` due to their inflexibility. However, we have a system where it was built using those asp:controls. I have no choice but to follow the way it was built.

Here is the problem, when I data bind `asp:CheckBoxList` control `DataTextField="Name"` and `DataValueField="ID"`, each input checkbox are using different names and when I need selected checkbox IDs, I have to loop through the whole `checkboxlist` to read the selected values.

If we use all those `input name="Types"` and read `Request.Form["Types"]` we can get all the selected ID values separated by commas, ",". In this way, I can avoid looping through all items in that `checkboxlist`. Is there any way we can do so that those `input checkbox` to use the same name?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I tried this and it is not working

```
ChkPropertyFeatures.Attributes.Add("name", "Types")
```

The reason I want to use the same name is not just to avoid loop at backend. I need to use jquery to select all those checkboxes by their name attribute. Yes, I know I can select by class name but I was wondering if I could change the name attribute of those checkboxes generated by Checkboxlist control.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815963/how-to-get-selected-item-in-checkboxlist-in-asp-net

Comment: Mate, I know how to get selected items. It is pretty simple loop. The point is I want to set the "name" attribute of those checkboxes generated by asp Checkboxlist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `CheckBoxList` generates a span wrapping each checkbox of the list:

```
<table id="CheckBoxList1">
    <tr>
        <td><span name="chenchi"><input id="CheckBoxList1_0" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$0" value="Uno" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_0">Uno</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span name="chenchi"><input id="CheckBoxList1_1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$1" checked="checked" value="Dos" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_1">Dos</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span name="chenchi"><input id="CheckBoxList1_2" type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxList1$2" checked="checked" value="Tres" /><label for="CheckBoxList1_2">Tres</label></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can change the name of each span dynamically this way:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        For Each c As ListItem In Me.CheckBoxList1.Items
                   c.Attributes("name") = "chenchi"
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you can use jquery to find out if each checkbox is checked:

```
var sps = $('#CheckBoxList1').find('[name="chenchi"]');
sps.each(function (i) {
       alert( $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked') ); 
});
```

Hope I understood your question well.

Comment: I appreciate your time, mate. I want to change the name of checkboxes, not span.

Comment: Thanks I have read that article the other day. It includes a lot of work. I'd rather choose to go with my own input checkbox inside the repeater then.

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the name of a web control from server side. If you need you can change the name attribute with javascript.

`$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("name", "Types");`

Comment: Well mate, I need to use Three CheckBox groups. They all will have the name attribute="Types". I have Types, Features and Categories groups.