# Checked items in a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, boolean, checkedlistbox

In `C#`, how can I determine if an item in a `CheckedListBox` is checked or not if I have the text of the `CheckListBoxItem`?

I am needing to loop through all `CheckedListBoxItems`, and retrieve the text and the checked state.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CheckedListBox.ObjectCollection items = checkedListBoxFileNames.Items;
foreach (var item in items)
{

}
```

I am not sure on how to determine if an item is checked or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need all checked items? You can use CheckedItems property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this foreach loop.

Try this:

```
if(this.m_CheckedListbox.CheckedItems.Contains("Item1")
{
   //make an action, if it's checked.
}

if(this.m_CheckedListbox.CheckedItems.Contains("Item2")
{
   //make an action, if it's checked.
}

// etc...

// this.m_CheckedListbox should be the name of your checked list box.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
IEnumerable<int> allChecked = (from item in chkBoxList.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
                           where item.Selected 
                           select int.Parse(item.Value));
```

more Details [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196007/linq-get-all-selected-values-of-a-checkboxlist-using-a-lambda-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
     //your code
}
```

Also check [CheckedListBox.CheckedItems Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Collection of checked items in this CheckedListBox.